# Pager visibility on infragistics ultrawebgrid

Tags: asp.net, infragistics, pager, ultrawebgrid

I have an infragistics ultrawebgrid v11.1 in my asp.net project and I've been asked to do away with paging on the grid.  Even if I turn paging off by setting `AllowPaging="false"`, the pager still appears, saying "jump to page 1 of 1" or something similar.

What can I do to hide the pager?  If I remember correctly the gridview pager has a `Visible` attribute, but the pager for the ultrawebgrid doesn't seem to have this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AllowPaging property is what controls whether the pager is visible.  If you are still seeing the pager even after setting this to false, check your code behind to verify that you aren't setting it to true anywhere after you set it to false.

You may also want to see if you have defined a custom pager and if that is what is showing.

If all you want to do is hide the existing pager, you could hide it with CSS as well though if there are multiple pages your users wouldn't be able to get to any other page.  Code to hide the pager with CSS:

```
UltraWebGrid1.DisplayLayout.Pager.PagerStyle.CustomRules = "display:none;";
```